# How can I set a variable placeholder inside a String in C

Tags: c, string, variables, sqlite

How can I set a variable placeholder inside a String in C?

For example, set **`ID`** from a variable `int id = 1234`.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO REV_ENTITY (ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY)" \
          "VALUES (99, 'John Doe', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";
```

**UPDATE**

I would like to have a final String that has the variable value in it.

This, as suggested doesn't work:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO REV_ENTITY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \  
    "VALUES (%d, 'REV', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";  

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, printf(sql, 999), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

I want something like this in Java:

```
String string = String.format("A string %s", aVariable);
```

Comment: `snprintf`? Or use the database-specific API variable binding (which just about *all* database API's have)?

Comment: maybe you want to check `printf`and its bretheren.

Comment: Take a look at [SQLite prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html). Prepare a statement then bind the parameters. Building your own sql in runtime is a bad idea that can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629501/how-to-sanitize-sql-queries-in-c?lq=1).

Comment: Not exactly (it's about mysql). Couldn't someone who used sqlite before write a *good* answer here please? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - How to use variables as part of an SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840798/c-how-to-use-variables-as-part-of-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `snprintf` mentioned in the other answer, you can use the `char *sqlite3_mprintf(const char*,...)` function from the sqlite3 API. It uses the sqlite `printf` built-in function and it allocates memory for the string using `sqlite3_malloc64()`. If everything goes well, it returns a pointer to the string , otherwise it returns `NULL`:

```
int id = 999;
char *sql;
sql = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO REV_ENTITY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (%d, 'REV', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 )", id);
if (sql != NULL) {
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE3_OK)
        /* Do some error handling. */
    sqlite3_free(sql);
}
```

Unlike `printf` functions family, `sqlite3_mprintf` does not have the luxury to report if the format is not correlated with the arguments. So, if it happens that you use GCC compiler, adding the following code can be useful:

```
extern char *sqlite3_mprintf(const char *format, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));
```

The other solution recommended in comments, is to use the sqlite3 prepare, step and finalize functions:

```
int id = 999;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
char *sql = "INSERT INTO REV_ENTITY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " \
            " VALUES (?, 'REV', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 )";
sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);
/* Bind id. */
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, id);
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
    printf("Insertion success\n");
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insertion error\n");
}
/* Finalize and destroy statement. */
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `snprintf`, pseudocode looks like this:

```
int idValue = 1234;
snprintf(buffer, bufferLength, "insert bla bla VALUES (%d, 'John Doe', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 )", idValue);
sqli_execute(buffer);
```

in your case it will look like:

```
//initialize sql variable before sprintfing into it
snprintf(sql, maximumSqlBufferLength "INSERT INTO REV_ENTITY (ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY) VALUES (%d, 'John Doe', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );", id);
```

Comment: Generally speaking avoid `sprintf`, prefer `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: I don't know the sqlite API, but I strongly assume it has parametrized / prepared statements. In this case, your answer is really bad advice.

Comment: @FelixPalmen it's exactly what OP asked for - he didn't ask for parametrized queries, also by example given by him I can assume he wanted way to insert value of variable on given position in string

Comment: just googled it: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html --- **never** use your own "sql string building" if you have a decent API for binding parameters. SQL injections are just around the corner!

Comment: @FelixPalmen that's true, but look at OPs example, he clearly wants sprintf-like function 
```I want something like this in Java:

String string = String.format("A string %s", aVariable);```

Comment: A good answer should give good advice. This is bad advice, IMHO. OPs java code of course is just as bad.